# discord.py member.edit(nick=nickname) not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot using discord.ext. I want to change the users nickname on the command `nick`.
For that I wrote following code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

# set prefix as "w!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="w!")

# do stuff when certain error occurs
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Error: Bot missing permissions.")
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Error: The command was not found")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Error: You don't have permission to do that.")

@bot.command()
# check if the user has the permission to change their name
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def nick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, nickname):
    await member.edit(nick=nickname)
    await ctx.send(f"Nickname was changed to {member.mention}.")

# reset the nickname if no new name was given
@nick.error
async def nick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        member = ctx.author
        await member.edit(nick=None)
        await ctx.send(f"Reset nickname to {member.mention}.")


bot.run("TOKEN")
```

When I enter `w!nick test name` in Discord it doesn't respond to the message and doesn't change my nickname. But when I just enter `w!nick` it resets my nickname.

Comment: Do you mention the user or do you type his name?

Comment: You are supposed to be able to only change your own name; if that's what you are talking about. @Mr_Spaar

Comment: In this case, why would you have a `member` argument?

Comment: Oh... you're right thats actually my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mr_Spaar for helping.
The solution:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def nick(ctx, *, nickname):
    member = ctx.author
    await member.edit(nick=nickname)
    await ctx.send(f"Nickname was changed to {member.mention}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def hnick(ctx, member: discord.Member, nick):
    await member.edit(nick=nick)
    await ctx.send(f'Nickname was changed for {member.mention} ')
```

Comment: What does the `client.comammnd(pass_context=True)` do? I've seen it before, but I think it's the old syntax for discord.ext. All of my other code works (for example banning and kicking users) using discord.ext without `client.comammnd(pass_context=True)`

Comment: `pass_context` is outdated. It was deleted during the [v1.0 migration](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=pass_context#context-changes)

Comment: So it won't fix my problem?